# How to fill $n$ free spaces with basic boxes

Tags: combinatorics

Sorry in advance for anything wrong with this question, I am not a mathematician so I really do not know how to search for my problem or how to explain/describe it.

Let's say that I have $n$ items to sell and different bookings each of which for some $m$ of those items: I need to maximize items selling.
The items price is irrelevant in my use case.

E.g.: 4 available items and bookings of 3,2,2: I need to find the (2,2) combination
E.g.: 11 available items and bookings of 10,7,5,4,4,3,2: both (5,4,2) and (4,4,3) are good

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: @JaapScherphuis With the special case that the value is equal to the weight. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem for a more accurate fit.